# Случайное изменение текста в одной из кнопок по нажатию на другую кнопку

Tags: c#

Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот создаю игру, крестики-нолики с участием компьютера. Вот игрок, например, нажал и поставил нолик в центре таблицы. Как сделать, чтобы как только выскочит по центру нолик, автоматически дописался крестик, в одной из четырех окружающих центральную позицию клеток? Надо сделать рандом, из 4-х кнопок, но как сделать это, не знаю. Прошу помочь мне, т.к. это я сохраню у себя в заметках и он мне еще понадобится. Выручайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @navi1893, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Можно положить кнопки в двумерный массив и исходить уже из него и индексов его элементов.

Comment: @dog_funtom нет, массив трогать не хочу. Рандомно как то хочется. Помочь сможешь?

Comment: @navi1893, вы дубок? Рандомный индекс массива ныне не актуально? =)

Comment: Так массивом вроде как раз проще всего сделать рандомно. В самом начале нужно занести все ссылки на кнопки в двумерный массив. При реакции на клик нужно определить, какой индекс соответствует этой кнопке, создать одномерный список и занести туда все ссылки на эти четыре кнопки. Затем нужно взять случайное число от 0 до длины списка и достать по полученному индексу нужную кнопку, и тогда уже можно нарисовать на ней крестик.